# python filter a list of dict to return a single dict

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dicts and need to filter on the 'name' key (values are guaranteed to be unique) in the nested dict in order to return a single dict.
I have a working solution but thought there would be more efficient/elegant/pythonic methods.

I tried dictionary comprehension but couldn't get my head around how it would iterate over the list

Solutions for for 2.7+ and 3 would be appreciated.

```
companies=[
    {
        'c01': {
            'name':'x',
            'address': '1 st'
        }
    },
    {
        'c02': {
            'name':'y',
            'address': '2 st'
        }
    },
]

company = [ c for c in companies if c.values() == [ v for v in c.values() if v['name']=='x'] ][0]

print company
```

Output:

```
{'c01': {'name': 'x', 'address': '1 st'}}
```

Comment: There is no `'loans'` in your sample data; what exactly do you hope for your code to do?

Comment: please clarify more about what do you want to get. also the expression company = x == y only gets true or false not any other value.

Comment: I am assuming OP only pasted a part of the list and hence committed the index with `loans`. If that is not the case, the code above will fail with an indexing error.

Comment: *Sigh* my failed attempts at masking

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. For loops can be enhanced though

```
company_dict = {}
for company in companies:
    for c in company:
        company_dict[c] = company.get(c)


print (company_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am always a fan of making things more readable than trying to play code golf - 
- although thats fun sometimes too :)

That being said, we can simply iterate through each element in your companies and look for the target name, then we return that company's info:

```
def get_target_company_info(companies):
    TARGET_NAME = 'loans'
    for company in companies:
        company_id = company.keys()[0]
        name_val = company.get(company_id).get('name')

        if name_val == TARGET_NAME:
            return company

    return None

company = get_target_company_info(companies)

print company
```

output:

```
{'c01': {'name': 'loans', 'address': '1 st'}}
```

To be a bit closer to what you wanted exactly, we can provide a filtering util method and filter as such:

method:

```
TARGET_NAME = 'loans'
def is_relevant_company(company):
    company_id = company.keys()[0]
    name_val = company.get(company_id).get('name')

    return company if name_val == TARGET_NAME else None
```

filter:

```
relevant_companies = filter(None, [is_relevant_company(company) for company in companies])
```

output:

```
[{'c01': {'name': 'loans', 'address': '1 st'}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[c for c in companies if any(['name' in c[x] and c[x]['name']=='x' for x in c])]
```

this filters out all companies with `name == "x"` and the output for your example will be:

```
[
    {'c01': {'name': 'x', 'address': '1 st'}}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want one dictionary, so there is not need for a list comprehension. Just iterate over the companies using a loop and break when you find your match (assuming your data structure is identical for each item in the list).

```
target = 'loans'
result = {}
for company in companies:
    data = company.values()[0]  # There is only one name & address per company record.
    if data['name'] == target:  # Check if the company name matches the target.
        result = data           # If so, set the result to the data for the target company.
        break                   # Then break from the loop, as you've found the only match.
```

For python 3, you need to make the following modification:

```
data = list(company.values())[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_company_with_name(name):
    return next(c for c in companies if c.values()[0]['name'] == name)
```

Using a generator expression is more efficient than a list comprehension, since it can stop searching once it finds a match without generating the rest of the list.